# 'NoneType' object is not iterable Error when using Sqlite3 and python to run query

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to create a table in a database on Jupyter Notebook using Python and sqlite3.
To avoid the table already exists error, I used the following code:

```
    q1 = '''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
        person_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
        first_name TEXT,
        last_name TEXT
    );
'''
run_query(q1)
```

However I received this error and I can't get rid of it.

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-948d42611e56> in <module>()
      7 
      8 '''
----> 9 run_query(q1)

<ipython-input-13-67c680d27fbe> in run_query(q)
      3 def run_query(q):
      4     with sqlite3.connect(db) as conn:
----> 5         return pd.read_sql(q,conn)
      6 
      7 def run_command(c):

/dataquest/system/env/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    398             sql, index_col=index_col, params=params,
    399             coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 400             chunksize=chunksize)
    401 
    402     try:

/dataquest/system/env/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
   1443         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
   1444         cursor = self.execute(*args)
-> 1445         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
   1446 
   1447         if chunksize is not None:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The table was created when I checked and the columns are there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the closing of q1. I don't know if it is related to your problem. But I understand your sql sentence should be enclosed by """.

Comment: thank you, it was in the original code . I have edited it on the question.

Comment: `run_query`  uses `read_sql` and for me `read_sql` was created to get data from database, not to create table or insert rows. `read_sql` should return rows from database but `CREATE` doesn't get any rows so it probalby return `None` and it has problem to iterate rows from `None`. If you use `sqlite` then you should use directly `sqlite.execute(query)`

Answer (score 0):

`run_query()` uses `read_sql()` which was created to read rows from database, not to create tables or insert rows. `read_sql()` expects that query will get rows from database and it try to iterate these rows but `CREATE` returns `None` - and you get `'NoneType' object is not iterable`

You should rather use directly `execute(query)` - ie.

```
 with sqlite3.connect(db) as conn:
      conn.execute(q1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation was very clear. It solved the problem.